# How to execute oracle java stored procedure in parallel

Tags: java, oracle, parallel-processing, procedure

I have a query like this:

```
select samplePackage.prepareMessage(t.message) as text 
from 
sampleSchema.sampleTable t;
```

sampleTable has large data (number of rows 30M)
prepareMessage is a java stored procedure.

```
private static String prepareMessage(String message) {
   //do some things...
   return preparedMessage;
}
```

I'm trying to execute this query in parallel. How can i do it?

Thanks.

Comment: try adding ` /*+ PARALLEL */` after the `select` then check the query plan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never tried it with Java function myself. But the approach should be as followos:

Run your query with the PARALLEL hint:

```
select /*+ PARALLEL(t) */ samplePackage.prepareMessage(t.message) as text 
from sampleSchema.sampleTable t;
```

To successfully execute the SELECT in parallel, Oracle needs to know that your Java function is safe for that. So you have to declare it either as PARALLEL_ENABLE or provide RESTRICT_REFERENCES.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION PREPARE_MESSAGE(message IN VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 PARALLEL_ENABLE
AS LANGUAGE JAVA
    NAME 'sampleSchema.samplePackage.prepareMessage(Java.lang.String) return Java.lang.String';
```

The query then becomes:

```
select /*+ PARALLEL(t) */ PREPARE_MESSAGE(t.message) as text 
from sampleSchema.sampleTable t;
```

There are further restrictions that apply to the function, e.g. it may not execute DML statements. Otherwise, a parallel execution isn't possible.

As I said: I haven't tried it with Java. But that's the direction to go.

**Update:** I've changed the code from using a package to using a function. It should be simpler like this.

Answer (score 2):

Use one of Oracle's prepackaged APIs, the DBMS_JOB package, to submit multiple jobs to a job queue and then run them in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to do it in parallel? What are you going to do with results?

The only think I think of running it in parallel is to execute it in one thread, then database server will return `ResultSet`. This `ResultSet` can be argument for threads that will retrieve part of database response (for example each thread will read 1M rows).

Comment: It seems to me that you're assuming that Java code executes a SQL query. Instead, it's the other way round: a SELECT statement calls a stored procedure written in Java. Levent Tokmak hasn't said anything about who runs the query.